# How to create tinyMCE dinamically with tinyMCE 3

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I am using `tinyMCE 3.9.3`. The page has already three tinyMCE. When a user clicks the hyperlink with id `add_line` a new tinyMCE should appear but for some reason it appears only a textarea. The id format of the new textarea is `comment+int` (for example the first new textarea has id `comment4`, the second one `comment5`...).
I tried to convert statically the first new textarea (`comment4`) to a tinyMCE but I failed.

This is the init of tinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
                //General options
                mode : "textareas",
                language : "<?=$_SESSION['interface_lang'];?>",
                valid_elements : '*[*]',
                forced_root_block: false ,
                theme : "advanced",
                plugins: "style,table,template","bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,cut,copy,paste,undo,,redo,link,unlink,image,cleanup,help,code,hr,removeformat,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,styleselect,sub,sup,forecolor,backcolor,forecolorpicker,backcolorpicker,charmap,visualaid,anchor,newdocument,blockquote,separator",
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "formatselect,fontsizeselect,styleselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,cut,copy,paste,undo,redo,link,unlink,template",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,image,hr,|,tablecontrols",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                // Skin options
                skin : "o2k7",
                skin_variant : "silver",
                content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}",
        
                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                //content_css : "css/editor.css",
        
                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                template_external_list_url : "/js/template_list.js",
                external_link_list_url : "/js/link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url : "/js/image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url : "/js/media_list.js",
                    
                    
                // Replace values for the template plugin
                template_replace_values : {
                    username : "xxx",
                    staffid : "xxx"
                },
                
                template_templates : [
                    
                    {
                        title : "Template",
                        src : "request_templ/tbl_detail3.html",
                        description : "Approfondimenti"
                    },
                ]
                
            });
```

That what happen when I click the hyperlink:

```
$(document).on("click","#add_line",function(){
                var num=parseInt($(this).attr("rel"))+1;
                $.post("post.php",{new_line:num,req:$(this).attr("req")},
                    function(data){
                        $("#table_answer").parent().append(data);
                        $( "#part"+num ).autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags2
                          });
                    });
                $(this).attr("rel",num);
                
                tinyMCE.remove('#comment4'); //here the problem
                tinyMCE.init('#comment4');
            });
```

In post.php the new textarea is created:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['new_line'])){
    $n=$_REQUEST["new_line"];
    $text="<tbody class='body_parts' rel=".$n."><tr class='line_add".$n."'>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts ui-autocomplete-input' id='part".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_namep"]." ".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts' id='reference".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_rif"]." ".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts' id='price".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_prixt"]." ".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts' id='operation".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_codopet"]." ".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts' id='description".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_libt"]." ".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td><input class='input_parts' id='time".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_tempt"]."".$n."'></td>";
    $text.="<td rowspan='2'><a rel='tps|".$_REQUEST["req"]."' class='new_fft'><img src='images/icons/add_line.png' style='width:20px'>".$interface["lbl_fft_tps"]."</a><br><a rel='pce|".$_REQUEST["req"]."' class='new_fft'><img src='images/icons/add_line.png' style='width:20px'>".$interface["lbl_fft_pce"]."</a></td>";
    $text.="</tr>";
    $text.="<tr class='line_add".$n."'>";
    $text.="<td style='height: 70px'>".$interface["lbl_comment"]."</td>";
    $text.="<td style='height: 70px' colspan=5><textarea style='width: 99%' class='input_parts' id='comment".$n."' placeholder='".$interface["tbl_comment"]." ".$n."'></textarea></td>"; //here the new textarea
    $text.="<td rowspan='2' style='border:0'><a class='down'><img src='images/down.png'></a><a class='up'><img src='images/up.png'></a><a class='delete_line' rel='".$n."'><img src='images/icons/trash_red.png'></a></td>";
    $text.="</tr></tbody>";
    echo $text;                   
}
```

So how can create a new tinyMCE dinamically? Can help?

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I must answer myself:

```
$(document).on("click","#add_line",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).attr("rel"))+1;
    $.post("post.php",{new_line:num,req:$(this).attr("req")},
        function(data){
            $("#table_answer").parent().append(data);
            var comment_id = 'comment' + num;
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, comment_id); //here
            $( "#part"+num ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags2
              });
        });
    $(this).attr("rel",num);
```

I used the function `execCommand` that transformed the textarea into a tinyMCE.